# How can I simplify and verify the logical equivalence using these laws?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

∼(p ∨∼q) ∨ (∼p ^ ~ q) ≡ ~p

Please help I don't know where to start.

These are the laws I need to list in each step when simplifying.

Commutative laws: p ∧ q ≡ q ∧ p
p ∨ q ≡ q ∨ p

Associative laws: (p ∧ q) ∧ r ≡ p ∧ (q ∧ r)

(p ∨ q) ∨ r ≡ p ∨ (q ∨ r)

Distributive laws: p ∧ (q ∨ r) ≡ (p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ r)

p ∨ (q ∧ r) ≡ (p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ r)

Identity laws: p ∧ t ≡ p

p ∨ c ≡ p

Negation laws: p ∨ ∼p ≡ t

p ∧ ∼p ≡ c

Double negative law: ∼(∼p) ≡ p

Idempotent laws: p ∧ p ≡ p

p ∨ p ≡ p

Universal bound laws: p ∨ t ≡ t

p ∧ c ≡ c

De Morgan’s laws: ∼(p ∧ q) ≡ ∼p ∨ ∼q

∼(p ∨ q) ≡ ∼p ∧ ∼q

Absorption laws: p ∨ (p ∧ q) ≡ p

p ∧ (p ∨ q) ≡ p

Negations of t and c: ∼t ≡ c

∼c ≡ t

Comment: Please use MathJax, [here's a guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\neg(p \vee \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \equiv \neg p$

$\begin{align}
\neg(p \vee \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) 
& \equiv (\neg p \wedge \neg \neg q) \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) & \text{D'Morgan}
\\ & \equiv (\neg p \wedge q) \vee (\neg p \wedge \neg q) & \text{Double Negation}
\\ & \equiv \neg p \wedge (q\vee \neg q) & \text{Distribution}
\\ & \equiv \neg p \wedge \top & \text{Conjunctive Negation}
\\ & \equiv \neg p & \text{Identity}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

First apply *De Morgan* to : $∼(p ∨∼q)$, followed by *Double Negation* on $∼∼q$.

Then apply *Distributivity* : $(∼p ∧ q) ∨ (∼p ∧ ∼q) ≡ p ∧ (q ∨ ∼q)$ followed by *Negation law* : $q ∨ ∼q ≡ t$.

Finally, simplify $∼p ∧ t$ with *Identity law*.